# how to extract elements from lists of two elements using purrr?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am using `quanteda`'s naive bayes model (`textmodel_nb`) to do some text-classification.

One of the output of the model is a list that contains the probabilities of each class. That is, if `nb` is my model, I see that

```
 > str(nb$PcGw)
 num [1:2, 1:462] 0.9446 0.0554 0.9259 0.0741 0.2932 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ classes : chr [1:2] "FALSE" "TRUE"
  ..$ features: chr [1:462] "hello" "john" "jan" "index" ..
```

and priting the list gives something like

```
 nb$PcGw
       features
classes         ny        john
  FALSE 0.94457605 0.92594799
  TRUE  0.05542395 0.07405201
```

I wanted to use `purrr` to extract this information and come up with a `data_frame` like

```
variable    P_TRUE     P_FALSE
'ny'        0.05542395 0.94457605
'john'      0.07405201 0.92594799
```

However, I was unable to do so. Can someone give me some help here?

Here is a working example using quanteda's own example:

```
txt <- c(d1 = "Chinese Beijing Chinese",
         d2 = "Chinese Chinese Shanghai",
         d3 = "Chinese Macao",
         d4 = "Tokyo Japan Chinese",
         d5 = "Chinese Chinese Chinese Tokyo Japan")
trainingset <- dfm(txt, tolower = FALSE)
trainingclass <- factor(c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N", NA), ordered = TRUE)

## replicate IIR p261 prediction for test set (document 5)
nb_test <- textmodel_nb(trainingset, trainingclass)

str(nb_test$PcGw)

 num [1:2, 1:6] 0.659 0.341 0.562 0.438 0.562 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ classes : chr [1:2] "Y" "N"
  ..$ features: chr [1:6] "Chinese" "Beijing" "Shanghai" "Macao"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a sample of the data using `dput`

Comment: yes, good idea. let me create a fake example

Comment: @docendodiscimus question updated!! thanks for helping

Comment: `purrr` seems overkill for this, would `data.frame(t(nb_test$PcGw))` not give you what you want?

Comment: Why not just transpose nb_test$PcGw? something like  `data.frame(t(nb_test$PwGc))`

Comment: If you need it in pipe `nb_test$PwGc %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% rownames_to_column('variable') %>% rename_at(2:3, ~ paste0("P_", c(TRUE, FALSE)))`

Comment: thanks for these nice comments. but the purpose is also to learn how to use `purrr`. Keep in mind that in my real code, this is incorporated into list columns, so I have to use `purrr` any ways. My problem is that I am unable to extract even single elements here: `nb_test$PcGw %>% map_chr(., "Chinese")` does not work

Comment: @akrun it is interesting to see that `nb$PcGw %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column(.,  'variable') %>% as_tibble()` works while 
`nb$PcGw %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% as_tibble(rownames_to_column(.,  'variable'))` fails. pretty mysterious to me

Comment: @NOOBIE I think you need to place it inside `{}`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that `nb$PcGw %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% { as_tibble(rownames_to_column(., 'variable'))}` because of the evaluation of arguments within the `%>%`

Comment: BTW, your `map_chr` is looping through individual elements of the matrix instead of columns i.e. `nb$PcGw %>% map(., ~ .x)`

Comment: Oh I see, but using your code now returns a vector `> nb_test$PcGw %>% map_chr(.,  ~.x)
 [1] "0.658537" "0.341463" "0.562500"`

Comment: in any case, @akrun do you mind posting your solution along with the comments we had here? I think its the best solution. I just wonder if if is possible to extract the TRUE FALSE probabilities for a single word directly using `purrr` and not resorting to the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, I added as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to get the transpose and format the columns, using `%>%`, transpose the matrix, convert to a `data.frame` , add a column of rownames (`rownames_to_column`) and rename if necessary

```
library(tidyverse)
nb_test$PwGc %>% 
     t %>% 
     as.data.frame %>% 
     rownames_to_column('variable') %>% 
     rename_at(2:3, ~ paste0("P_", c(TRUE, FALSE)))
```

Based on the communication with OP, if we need to nest some statements inside the `%>%` wrap it with `{}`

```
nb_test$PcGw %>% 
      t %>%
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      {as_tibble(rownames_to_column(., 'variable'))}
```

Or just use

```
nb_test$PcGw %>%
    t %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    rownames_to_column(., 'variable') %>% 
    as_tibble()
```